# Mongoose 5.0.15 / MongoDB 3.6.4 Cast to Array Failed for value [NaN, NaN]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, restful-architecture

**Context**

This is not a [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383207/mongoose-casterror-cast-to-array-failed-for-value-when-trying-to-save-a-model)

*As explained in detail below I scoured the web and read about 20 similar bugs or articles and nothing out there has solved this issue, as yet.*

I am developing a location-based application in two different OS, Windows 8.1 and Linux/Ubuntu (16.4)
The following engines are running in the Ubuntu machine; however, the error I get is exactly the same regardless of dependency version or OS.

`Node.js ~4.2.6`
`NPM ~ 3.5.2`
`MongoDB ~ 3.6.4`
`Mongoose ~5.0.15`

**What is the current behavior?**

I am getting this error, despite having spent days researching similar bugs and testing/trying different things.
From Postman:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "coords": {
        "message": "Cast to Array failed for value \"[ NaN, NaN ]\" at path \"coords\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"[ NaN, NaN ]\"",
        "kind": "Array",
        "value": [
            null,
            null
        ],
        "path": "coords",
        "reason": {
            "message": "Cast to [number] failed for value \"[null]\" at path \"coords\"",
           ....
     "_message": "Location validation failed",
     "message": "Location validation failed: coords: Cast to Array failed for value \"[ NaN, NaN ]\" at 
      path \"coords\", name: Path `name` is required., openingTimes.0.days: Path `days` is required., 
      openingTimes.0.closed: Path `closed` is required.",
       "name": "ValidationError"
  }
```

My Assumption here is that this is not just a problem due to Cast Error but that something is wrong with the Schema for this specific POST method. Note that the same Schema is used for GET methods and it works like charm.

**Steps to reproduce.**

At this point of the development I am designing the API and am using Mongoose's Schema to model the data.

**This is the model for the API:**

```
const` mongoose = require("mongoose");
const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   author: String,
   rating: {$type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
   timestamp: {$type: Date, "default": Date.now},
    reviewText: String
}, {typeKey: "$type"});

const openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  days: {$type: String, required: true},
  opening: String,
  closing: String,
  closed: {$type: Boolean, required: true}
 }, {typeKey: "$type"});

const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {$type: String, required: true},
  rating: {$type: Number, "default": 0, min: 0, max: 5},
  address: String,
  facilities: [String],
  coords: {$type: [[Number]], index: '2dsphere', required:true},
  openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
  reviews: [reviewSchema]
 }, {typeKey: "$type"});

 mongoose.model("Location", locationSchema);
```

Note I am using `typeKey` as suggested in different posts and as suggested as well in Mongoose documentation for geoJSON objects. Even without using `typeKey` the error persist.

**Controller**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Loc = mongoose.model("Location");

const theEarth = (function(){
const earthRadious = 6371;    
const getRadsFromDistance = (distance) => {
    return parseFloat(distance / earthRadious);
 };

 return {
    getRadsFromDistance: getRadsFromDistance
 };

 })();

var sendJsonResponse = (res, status, content) =>{
  res.status(status);
  res.json(content);
 };

module.exports.locationsCreate = (req, res) => {
   Loc.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address,
    facilities: req.body.facilities,
    coords: [parseFloat(req.body.lng), parseFloat(req.body.lat)],
    openingTimes: [{
        days: req.body.days1,
        opening: req.body.opening1,
        closing: req.body.closing1,
        closed: req.body.closed1
     }]
    }, function (err, location){
            if (err){
                sendJsonResponse(res, 400, err);
            }
            else{
                sendJsonResponse(res, 201, location);
            }
   });


 };
```

**The expected behavior is to POST the dummy location created in Postman:**

POST /api/locations HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:3000

name: Coffee BlaBlaBla

address: 435 High Street Paradise, Midnowhere

facilities: Hot Coffee,Breakfast,Wifi

lng: 2.3567

lat: 41.5676

days1: Monday - Friday

opening1: 8:00am

closing1: 5:00pm

closed1: false

Cache-Control: no-cache

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

If someone with a fresh eye knows what is going, that would be phenomenal. 
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose, CastError: Cast to Array failed for value when trying to save a model that contains a model.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383207/mongoose-casterror-cast-to-array-failed-for-value-when-trying-to-save-a-model)

Comment: I think body not parsed correctly, or You've not picked correct request content type for Your data, or You've issue with json object that You send to backend. Please add which body parser You use in Your express app and also add screenshot from the interface of postman where You define request body and etc.

Comment: @DanCrews thiis is not a duplicate of the question you are referring to. If you read the post I have already tackled the potential issue of `type`, `typeForm` and `keyType`. This is a problem of Schema declaration, I am almost certain about it. The GET methods both retrieve the right documents but without the coordinates. When I use the coordinates for the POST' requests I get the error. Still working at it

Comment: @num8er not a body-parser issue. The POST method I use it is in the code above and it is correct. Arghhhhh. Days I am working on this bug. This may well be an issue with Arrays on objects in Mongoose 5.x.x but cannot confirm yet

Comment: have You tried to define it like: `$type: [Number]` ? cuz I see You're pushing array of 2 numbers to field type of nested array (array in array). or try to create record like: `coords: [ [parseFloat(req.body.lng), parseFloat(req.body.lat)]  ],`  (see extra square-brackets)

Comment: @num8er yes you are right that was another attempt but the original code is an Array (not nested array). Same error

Comment: can You do: `console.log(req.body)`  before calling Location.create and add that output to Your question?

Comment: @num8er it returns an empty object {}.

Comment: ok, then again asking: `which body parser You use?` and `how You've attached that body parser?`  Cuz I saw in Your error object that You've many empty fields that is required by ODM (mongoose). See "message" field in error object.

Comment: @num8er I am in chat now

Comment: don't forget to share with us if You've fixed (:

Comment: As of yet, I have not. It is true the `body-parser` as for express doc should be set in the middleware to parse json and multi-x forms. But that is not the issue as with both `express.json` and `express.bodyParser` the body still does not populate. So the test returns still an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now solved. As suspected, this had nothing to do with previous questions asked here and in GitHub. The problem was the request passed through Postman wasn't fit for the `mongoose schema`. This was because of the **validation requirements** that various documents' fields had and so it only took one tiny error in formulating each request to throw the error.

Once I started testing the `req.body` elements one by one, I got continuous errors but the server, however, was starting to log some fields correctly, although in isolation and one by one. That was an eye opener to test all the fields until I found the right combination. Counter-intuitively the `req.body` returned an empty object at first because the request was broken in the first instance.

All the previous attempts i.e. changing `type` for `keyType`, using the `body-parser` instead of the `express` built-in middleware to process JSON and URLs requests, etc, were good attempts but all futile.

Thank you all for contributing and looking into this with me.