# How to save multiple categories for a single post with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

So i have 2 schemas, Game and Category:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const gameSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'category'
    }],

});

module.exports = { Game: mongoose.model('game', gameSchema) };
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
});

module.exports = { Category: mongoose.model('category', categorySchema) };
```

I'm trying to save a new Game that contains multiple categories:

```
const newGame = new Game({
            title: req.body.title,
            description: req.body.postDescription,
            category: req.body.category,
        });

        newGame.save().then((game, err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                req.flash('success-message', 'New Game Created');
                res.redirect('/admin/games');
            }
        });
```

And here is my front-end code (handlebars). I'm using tag input plugin for jquery to get an array of categories

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
<select multiple name="category" id="category" class="cat form-control">
       {{#select game.category}}
       {{#each categories}}
       <option value="{{title}}">{{title}}</option>
       {{/each}}
       {{/select}}
</select>
```

Error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: game validation failed: category: Cast to Array failed for value "[ 'ACTION','MOBILE','RPG' ]" at path "category"
```

I would like assistance in understanding why this error would occur, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose, CastError: Cast to Array failed for value when trying to save a model that contains a model.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383207/mongoose-casterror-cast-to-array-failed-for-value-when-trying-to-save-a-model)

Comment: No unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

‍ **You can try** this code below  to save your game and your category.

```js
const jobQuerys = [];

const { category: categories, title, postDescription: description } = req.body;

// save category
categories.forEach(title => {
  const category = new Category({ title })
  jobQuerys.push(category.save());
});

// get all category was saved
const categoriesResult = await Promise.all(jobQuerys);

// category id temporary
const arrCategoryId = [];

// add category._id to arrCategoryId
categoriesResult.forEach(category => {
  arrCategoryId.push(category._id);
});

// save game with categoryId
const game = new Game({ title, description, category: arrCategoryId });
const result = await game.save();

// show result
console.log(result);
```

> Make sure, because we're using `await` in this code, so in your function, please add `async`.

I hope it can help you .